# Overriding _open Method

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

Here is example, here is code snip from builtin python Logging:

```
class StreamHandler(Handler)
    def __init__(self, stream=None):
        Handler.__init__(self)
        self.stream = stream

class FileHandler(StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, mode='a'):
        StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())

    def _open(self):
        stream = open(self.name, self.mode)
        return stream

class MyFileHandler(FileHandler)
    def _open(self):
        stream = open(self.name, self.mode, 0)
        return stream
```

I am trying to override the `_open` function. So I did above and is not working. How to overrode `_open` in above case?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea where you got these classes from tbh. `Filehandler`, as used in the `logging` module, is defined in [`logging.__init__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/93d5f91fff5740b463980797a04f3d5f1d5f1a51/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1008) and in its `__init__` it sets a couple of attributes you should be using in your `_open` call. Specifically `self.baseFilename`, the name of the file to use.

Your class, with `_open` being the only thing implemented, should look like this:

```
from logging import FileHandler

class MyFileHandler(FileHandler):
    def _open(self):
        stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, 0)
```

and since you set buffering to `0` you should be providing a mode to open it in binary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
Sorry code was snippet. I am importing from logging module.

```
class FileHandler(StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, mode='a'):
        StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())    <--
```

I want to overide the stream(above second argument)  that is passed **init**